# Limit of $(a_{n+1}-a_{n}) e^{-a_{n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Consider a sequence $\{a_{n}\}$ satisfying $$a_{n+2}-2a_{n+1}+a_{n} \geq C > 0$$
Do we have : $\lim_{n\to \infty}(a_{n+1}-a_{n}) e^{-a_{n}}=0$ ?

 
PS : This question is inspired from [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/298096/asymptotic-behavior-of-fxn-e-fx) continuous version which is still unanswered.

Comment: Could {[a(n+2] - a(n+1)] - [a(n+1] - a(n)]} > C > 0 be of any use ? It is just a suggestion since I am totally incompetent in this area (and so many other !).

Comment: It looks like the discrete equivalent of strict convexity, but i'm not sure if leads to the same conclusions (for example that $(a_{n+1}-a_{n})$ is increasing and goes to +infinity and that $a_{n}$ goes to +infinity...)

Comment: I totally agree with you. It was just an idea coming to my mind when I saw the symmetry in your formula.

Comment: Continuous version is answered now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Put $a_1=1$ and $a_{n+1}=a_n+e^{a_n}$. Then $(a_{n+1}-a_n)e^{-a_n}=1\not\to0$, and $$a_{n+2}-2a_{n+1}+a_n=a_{n+2}-a_{n+1}-(a_{n+1}-a_n)=e^{a_{n+1}}-e^{a_n}>e^{a_n}(a_{n+1}-a_n)=e^{2a_n}>1.$$